# after pressing send, typed text in keyboard is not disappearing

Tags: ios, swift

This only started in Swift 3 in a custom app i'm developing.
Basically, when I type something into the keyboard and press send,
the text doesn't disappear. It just stays there as if you didn't press send (but you did).

I'm using JSQMessagesViewController but I have it implemented correctly I think as it was working before Swift3. I haven't seen anyone else have this issue ever, at least it seems that way while googling.

This bug is tested on both the iOS default keyboard and SwiftKey.

The keyboards are working properly on other chat apps, like hangouts or snapchat, etc. So I think it's something specific with my app.

I'm not sure what code is relevant to include, let me know and i'll edit this post to include it. i'm using [IQKeyboardManagerSwift](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/tree/master/IQKeyboardManagerSwift) extension but the bug persists when I disable that as well.

[image: screenshot of the bug]

Answer (score 1):

ok i fixed it. not sure why it was working before but stopped working randomly

i added a self.finishSendingMessage function in JSQMessagesViewController and that fixed it.

```
    override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    createChatsMessagesFor(self.chatID!, senderId: senderId, text: text)
    finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has no code, it's difficult to help, but...

Make sure your class includes `UITextFieldDelegate` in the class declaration, and do this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This will resign the keyboard when hitting "enter".

You could also add an IBAction which calls `textField.resignFirstResponder()` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, as I understand it, resignFirstResponder() is for hiding the keyboard. I don't want to hide the keyboard though, I want the text that I typed to disappear after I press send. So i don't know if firstResponder has anything to do wit this bug.

Comment: Ah, I'll correct as soon as I get near my computer.